# Button_to in Ruby on Rails bad route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, link-to

I'm trying to use the `button_to` rails helper. I wrote the following code:

`<%= button_to 'Edit Item', edit_item_path(@item), :class => 'mark-button' %>`

and got the following error message

`No route matches "/items/1/edit"`

But when I refresh the page it goes to the appropriate action. The URL of the page i get is `localhost:3000/items/1/edit` which is the correct URL. If I switch the `button_to` command to `link_to` the page loaded with no errors. Meaning this code:

`<%= link_to 'Edit Item', edit_item_path(@item), :class => 'mark-button' %>`

loads fine. Maybe there is some feature of `button_to` I'm not aware of, but I am at a lost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be misusing button_to. I've always thought that if you're linking to the edit action, you should be using link_to. Buttons seem to be for actions that need to post/put data such as updating a form or deleting a record.

Update:

By default, button_to uses POST instead of GET. Hence it working when you just visit the URL (ie GET).

Comment: How can i override this feature?

Comment: If you want it to look like a button, I would use link_to and use a CSS class that makes your link look like a button.  Great article here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/18/designing-css-buttons-techniques-and-resources/

Comment: @nayish you can set the method to get: `button_to 'edit', edit_item_path(@item), :method => :get`

Answer (score 2):

button_to defaults to POST, and link_to defaults to GET.

If you really need button_to you can change the default method to GET for edit and other links.

for ex:

```
<%= button_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user), :method => :get %>
```

Answer (score -2):

Ruby -v 2.8.6, Rails 6.1.4.1

<%= button_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item), :method => :get %> because with expression (@item) you do not define the object you want to edit, because (@item) it is not a specific object, there are several and you need to define only the one you want to edit, :method => :get this method is perfect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).