# Why does "link_to" work but not "button_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Why would this work?

```
<%= link_to "New Item", new_site_care_path, {:class => "button_bottom"} %>
```

And this (the only change is from link_to to button_to)...

```
<%= button_to "New Item", :url => new_site_care_path, {:class => "button_bottom"} %>
```

...produces:

```
No route matches "/site_cares/new"
```

***UPDATE - ROUTE INFO -*** 
route file:

```
resources :site_cares, :except => :show
```

rake routes:

```
new_site_care GET /site_cares/new(.:format) {:action=>"new", :controller=>"site_cares"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `button_to` uses post by default, my ROR route skills are a bit rusty but I think the route you've shown uses GET.

There's further info in this question - [Button_to in Ruby on Rails bad route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708671/button-to-in-ruby-on-rails-bad-route)

Comment: probably violate sensibilities of some of the folks in the rails community, but created my own "link_to" button with a div. I don't think users notice that buttons are for posts and links are used elsewhere do you? ps... glad i got to put you over the 2000 mark... not that u notice that kind of thing :=]

Comment: @Jay -Thanks for pushing me over the 2000 barrier :) Think you're definitely doing the right thing with the button!